# Spring Boot Data JPA NativeQuery throws Syntax-Error on Query working in MySQL Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am using `Spring Boot Data JPA` and want to query data from my MySQL database. I wrote a query in MySQL workbench that works out perfectly fine in it and now I'd like to use exactly that query in my Repository as a native query.

This is the query working my MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT s.* FROM fips.schedule s 
inner join lecture_object lo on s.id_lecture_object = lo.id_lecture_object 
inner join lecture_semester ls on lo.id_lecture_semester = ls.id_lecture_semester 
inner join lecture_semester_has_possible_lecturers ll on ls.id_lecture_semester = ll.id_lecture_semester
where s.id_scenario = 1 and ll.id_lecturer=103 and ll.status="fixed";
```

This is the line in my Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ScheduleRepository extends CrudRepository<Schedule, Integer> {

    @Query(value="SELECT s.* FROM fips.schedule s " +
            "inner join lecture_object lo on s.id_lecture_object = lo.id_lecture_object " +
            "inner join lecture_semester ls on lo.id_lecture_semester = ls.id_lecture_semester " +
            "inner join lecture_semester_has_possible_lecturers ll on ls.id_lecture_semester = ll.id_lecture_semester" +
            "where s.id_scenario = :scenarioId " +
            "and ll.id_lecturer = :lecturerId " +
            "and ll.status = \"fixed\"", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Schedule> getAllByFixedLecturerAndScenario(@Param("lecturerId") int lecturerId, @Param("scenarioId") int scenarioId);
}
```

Now upon execution I get the following error:

```
2020-09-22 18:02:15.607 DEBUG 7156 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : SELECT s.* FROM fips.schedule s inner join lecture_object lo on s.id_lecture_object = lo.id_lecture_object inner join lecture_semester ls on lo.id_lecture_semester = ls.id_lecture_semester inner join lecture_semester_has_possible_lecturers ll on ls.id_lecture_semester = ll.id_lecture_semesterwhere s.id_scenario = ? and ll.id_lecturer = ? and ll.status = "fixed"
2020-09-22 18:02:15.608  WARN 7156 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
2020-09-22 18:02:15.608 ERROR 7156 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's.id_scenario = 1 and ll.id_lecturer = 103 and ll.status = "fixed"' at line 1
2020-09-22 18:02:15.610 ERROR 7156 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] c.v.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler      : 
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

It seems like there is something wrong with the `WHERE`-clause, but it is exactly the same statement that works in MySQL WB. Am I missing something on the native queries? I also tried changing the `"` around `fixed` to `'`, which did not change the outcome (the same goes for replacing the `status = "fixed"` by `status LIKE "fixed"`.

Comment: When changing "fixed" to 'fixed', did you also remove the \ escapes ?

Comment: Yep, it said `status = 'fixed'` - i also removed that part of the where-statement to check if that might be the problem, the outcome did not change.

Comment: Is using a stored procedure an option? Otherwise i have to pass, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space in the end of the string before "where". Change

```
on ls.id_lecture_semester = ll.id_lecture_semester"
```

to

```
on ls.id_lecture_semester = ll.id_lecture_semester "
```

Comment: Also it is better to list the column names, e.g. s.column1, s.column2,...,  in the SELECT instead of s.*

Comment: This is kind of embarassing, really fixed it :D               Wouldn't it be better to select `s.*` instead of column names in case something on the database table changes (e.g. a flag gets added - you'd basically have to adjust all the queries)? Or what is the advantage of listing the attributes over `s.*`